# populating listview from database with sqlite asset helper without extending listactivity

Tags: java, android, sqlite, listview, android-listview

By using a SQLIte Asset Helper to get data from database...
my database contains two tables-
(1)android_metadata
(2)topiccontent(_id,uname,utopicname)

i have created a separate database helper class whose code is as follows

```
    public class ExternalDbOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {


    public static String DB_NAME = "cosmcontent.db";
    public ExternalDbOpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);}

    public Cursor getUnits()
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
        SQLiteQueryBuilder qb = new SQLiteQueryBuilder();

        String [] sqlSelect = {"_id","uname","utopicname"};
        String sqlTables = "unitcontent";

        qb.setTables(sqlTables);
        Cursor c = qb.query(db, sqlSelect, null, null, null, null, "utopicname ASC");

        c.moveToFirst();
        return c;

    }



    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {}}
```

and so the data from here i wanted to show in listview on my MainAcitvity..

After doing a lot of research i actually not getting around with the code for the custom adapter which will fill the listview.
I want to show two columns data in my each row of listview.
the header of the each row will be the data from column named "utopicname" and the data following it will be from column "uname".
I am trying to show the content from the column "utpoicname" in ascending order.
and so does wanted the content frin column "uname" should appear in relation with "utopicname" sorted order.
I dont want listactivity to be extended on my MainActivity.
any help will be appreciated.
the code for my MainActivity is as follows-

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity
{

private Cursor units;
private ExternalDbOpenHelper dbOpen;
ListView lv; 


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    dbOpen = new ExternalDbOpenHelper(this);
    units = dbOpen.getUnits();

    ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
    lv.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.eaach_row,units,
    new String[]{ExternalDbOpenHelper.KEY_UTOPICNAME,ExternalDbOpenHelper.KEY_UNAME},
    new int[]{R.id.topicname,R.id.unitname},0));
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
    {
         @Override
         public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v,int position, long id) 
         {
              Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
          }
    });
}}
```

**LOG CAT**

```
07-01 18:34:12.900: W/SQLiteAssetHelper(1017): copying database from assets... 
07-01 18:34:12.900: W/SQLiteAssetHelper(1017): database copy complete
07-01 18:34:12.940: I/SQLiteAssetHelper(1017): successfully ope cosmcontent.db
07-01 18:34:13.032: D/AndroidRuntime(1017): Shutting down VM
07-01 18:34:13.032: W/dalvikvm(1017): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught                          exception (group=0xa6224288)
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start    activity ComponentInfo{com.example.tutscosm/com.example.tutscosm.MainActivity}:    java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at com.example.tutscosm.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:33)
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
07-01 18:34:13.036: E/AndroidRuntime(1017):     ... 11 more
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
>
<ListView 
android:id="@+id/list"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
</ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

eaach_row.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="horizontal" 
android:padding="10dp" >
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/topicname"
android:layout_width="150dp"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"                  
android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
<TextView 
android:id="@+id/unitname"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
android:layout_below="@id/topicname"
android:layout_centerVertical="true"
/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: what is null exactly?

Comment: @njzk2 no worries on this query anymore friend.. i  got it figured out using the answers... Thanks for your concern

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about using a `CursorAdapter`? And a `SimpleCursorAdapter`?

> Standard constructor.
>
> Parameters 
>   **context**   The context where the ListView associated with this
>   SimpleListItemFactory is running layout
>
> resource identifier of a
>   layout file that defines the views for this list item. The layout file
>   should include at least those named views defined in "to"
>
> **c** The
>   database cursor. Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.
>
> **from**  A list of column names representing the data to bind to the UI.
>   Can be null if the cursor is not available yet.
>
> **to**    The views that
>   should display column in the "from" parameter. These should all be
>   TextViews. The first N views in this list are given the values of the
>   first N columns in the from parameter. Can be null if the cursor is
>   not available yet. flags  Flags used to determine the behavior of the
>   adapter, as per CursorAdapter(Context, Cursor, int).

```
ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(...);
listView.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(
   this,  // The context
   R.layout.layoutToShow,  // The layout of the row to show
   dbOpen.getUnits(),  // Here the cursor where the data is, i used .getUnits()
                       // but it can be anything
   new String[] { tables to show },  // here the tables to show
   new int[] { where to put data? },  // here where to show? the IDs
                                     // of the layout elements where put data.
   0
);
```

Check out [`SimpleCursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorAdapter.html#SimpleCursorAdapter%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.database.Cursor,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D%29) for more info, or more general class which gives to you more options if you need [`CursorAdapter`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CursorAdapter.html)

Comment: @MarcoAcieno i tried your code but my log cat shows a runtime exception...it is like java.lang.Runtime exception. unable to start activity

Comment: How can i help you without more info? Please add the logcat.

Comment: Check MainActivity.java line 33. Something is null.

Comment: from the line-33 the code starts is-----                lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
        lv.setAdapter(new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.eaach_row,dbOpen.getUnits(),new String[]{ExternalDbOpenHelper.KEY_UTOPICNAME,ExternalDbOpenHelper.KEY_UNAME },
new int[]{R.id.topicname,R.id.unitname},0));

Comment: You don't need to "guess", start the debugger and check what is null in the line.

Comment: Its probably because your ListView has the wrong id in your layout. Try just using `R.id.list` instead of `android.R.id.list`

Comment: @Simon Thank you for response. i tried the suggestion of your's and now it is showing null state on "savedInstanceState" any idea??

Comment: @MarcoAcierno had included my xml files.. please take a look at those and see if you get any idea

Comment: I'm not a mind reader. You'll have to update your question's Activity java code or paste bin and link in a reply comment

Comment: @MarcoAcierno can you please help me in migrating this code into listfragment without extending the "Listfragmet"????

Answer (score -1):

You should do this:

```
public Class Units{
    String utopicname;
    public Units(Strign utopicname){
         this.utopicname = utopicname;
    }
    public void setUtopicName(String utopicname){
         this.utopicname=utopicname;
    }
    public String getUtopicName(){
         return utopicname;
    }
}

//////////////////////////

ArrayList<Units> units;
Cursor c = dbOpen.getUnits();
do{
    Units unit = new Units(c.getString(2));
    units.add(unit);
}while(c.moveToNext());

ListView listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
AdapterLists adapterlists = new AdapterLists(this,R.layout.main_layout, units);
listview.setAdapter(adapterlists);

class AdapterLists extends ArrayAdapter {
    Activity context = null;
    public AdapterLists(Activity context, int layout,ArrayList<Units> units) {
        super(context, layout, canales);
        this.context = context;
    }

    public View getView(final int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
        View item = inflater.inflate(R.layout.unit_row, null);
        TextView ui_unit_utopicname = (TextView)item.findViewById(R.id.txt_row);
        String dat_unit_utopicname = units.get(position).getUtopicName();
        ui_unit_utopicname.setText(dat_unit_utopicname);
        return item;
    }
}
```

You need to crerate a layout (main_layout.xml) whith a TextView (txt_row.xml)

Comment: You need to add Units class whith setUtopicName() and getUtopicName(), then, yo have to add: do {Units unit = new Units(c.getString(1));units.add(unit);} while (c.moveToNext()); Now you have an Arraylist<Units>

Comment: I am not getting how to that. I have just started working around in android. If you can help me further will be much appreciated.

Comment: the class Units variables will automatically be bind with the data from database?

Comment: No, you do that in do{ }while(), for each element in cursor you create an "unit" object, units array is an object that contains "unit" objects. You know? You can contact me by mail if you want, se my profile

Comment: Thank you for your answers.. I got this one figured out.. Nut sure will might need to brush up more.. Will contact you sure...

Comment: cant find your email id

Comment: check here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Diego%C2%AE you will find it